# How to tell when the DOM is ready in Dart?

Tags: dom, dart

I want to get some information about some DOM elements after the page is ready, but I haven't figured out how to tell when this is.  I've tried using `document.on.contentLoaded` and `document.on.readyStateChange`, but neither seem to work.  In the following code, `onContentLoaded()` and `onReadyChanged()` never get called.

```
class WhiteTrace {

  WhiteTrace() {    
  }

  void onContentLoaded(Event e) {
    print("onContentLoaded");
    // This never gets called 
  }

  void onReady() {
    print("onReady");
    // Do stuff
  }

  void onReadyChanged(Event e) {
    print("onReadyStateChanged");
    // This never gets called
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      onReady();
      document.on.readyStateChange.remove(onReadyChanged);
    }
  }

  void onResize(Event e) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  void run() {
    write("Hello World!");
    document.on.contentLoaded.add(onContentLoaded);

    window.on.resize.add(onResize);

    document.on.readyStateChange.add(onReadyChanged); 
    print("readyState: " + document.readyState);
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      document.on.readyStateChange.remove(onReadyChanged);
      onReady();
    }
  }

  void write(String message) {
    // the HTML library defines a global "document" variable
    document.query('#status').innerHTML = message;
  }
}

void main() {
  new WhiteTrace().run();
}
```

Comment: You can always use `window.on.load`. The correct DOM event is `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` so try `document.on.DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: I can't find any event called "DOMContentLoaded" in the DocumentEvents interface. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: DOMContentLoaded is the w3c defined name for the event. I don't know anything about dart or it's DOM emulation layer. There must be some mechanism to get dart to compile js that looks like `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cb)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `document.on.contentLoaded` is the equivalent of `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Here's the relevant bug, you might want to star it: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=619

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to care if the DOM is loaded - Darts main does only start when the DOM is fully loaded.

http://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/

"Dart code executes only after the page is parsed. Dart programmers can assume that the DOM is fully loaded."

Comment: This basically means he's listening on an event that has already fired. Thus is event handler never gets fired

Comment: The code handles this case already, but anyway I don't think this is true anymore. Initially I get a readyState of "loading" and a query on some HTML elements returns null. Later on I get "complete" and a valid HTML element. The link you included also states: "We are considering allowing Dart code to run as soon as a script is loaded"