# Dart vs JavaScript - Are they compiled or interpreted languages?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, dart, interpreter

Is Dart considered to be a compiled or an interpreted language? 
The same question holds for JavaScript.

The reason for the question:

I've been [watching an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Gsrvya_T2Y) with the founders of dart, and in 7:10 Lars Bak said that:

> "When you [...] in a JavaScript program, you actually execute JavaScript before you start running the real program. In Dart, you don't execute anything before the first instruction in main is being executed".

It sounded to me that he's saying that JavaScript is a compiled language while Dart is an interpreted language. Is it true?

Isn't the Dart VM a compiler?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on the definition of "interpreted" and "compiled" language. And even then, it always depends on the implementation.

What Lars meant is that JavaScript builds its class structures (and other global state) by executing code. In Dart the global state is described by the language syntax and thus only needs parsing (and even then most of it can be skipped first). As a consequence Dart programs can start executing "real" code faster than JavaScript programs.

This obviously only holds for the Dart VM, since programs that have been compiled to JavaScript must use JavaScript mechanisms to build their classes.

Edit (more details):

Take, for example, the following extremely simple class `A`:

In Dart:

```
class A {
  final x;
  A(this.x);
  foo(y) => y + x;
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
function A(x) { this.x = x; }
A.prototype.foo = function(y) { return y + this.x; }
```

When the Dart VM starts up it starts by going through the program. It sees the `class` keyword, reads the class-name (`A`) and could then simply skip to the end of the class (by counting opening and closing braces, making sure they are not in strings). It does not care for the contents of `A`, until `A` is actually instantiated. Now, in reality, it actually looks through the class and finds all the members, but it does *not* read the contents of methods until they are needed. In any case: it does this in a very fast processing step.

In JavaScript things get more complicated: a fast VM can skip the actual body of the function `A` (similar to what Dart does), but when it sees `A.prototype.foo = ...` it needs to execute code to create the prototype object. That is, it needs to allocate a function object (`A`), look up its prototype property, change this object (adding a new property) with a new function object. In other words: in order to even see that you have a class you need to execute code.

Comment: Thanks @Florian Loitsch , but can you please explain what you meant by "In Dart, the global state is described by the language syntax and thus needs only parsing". Doesn't every language need parsing? I'd appreciate it if you could please explain it again.

Comment: `As a consequence Dart programs can start executing "real" code faster than JavaScript programs`. This isn't entirely correct in the browser, since `main()` is called *after* the DOM has been loaded. JS can execute before the DOM is ready, so in a practical application, JS can execute sooner. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435519/how-to-tell-when-the-dom-is-ready-in-dart). But in terms of the language, you're correct.

Answer (score 6):

Dart as programming language in its primary implementation can be presented as a `virtual machine` (VM), which is the runtime of programs written in that language.

Current `virtual machine` implemented as the `"just-in-time"` (JIT) runtime environment engine.

This means that program `not interpreted` but `compiled`. But this compilation process (translating `source code` to `machine instructions`) is `stretched in time` for an unknown period.

This allows virtual machine to `defer performing certain operations indefinitely` or `never performing them`.

Assume you have a very `big and complex program` with a `lot of classes` which `may be never be` used in current `short lifetime session` of program execution.

JIT compilation allow not compile all unused classes but just parse it to special `tokens`.
These tokens later will be used (`on demand`) for translating them to `intermadiate language` for constructing `machine code`.

This process is `transparent for user of program`. Compiled (to machine code) only that source code that required for the correct working of the program.

Some source code can be never compiled what `save a lot of time`.

**Conclusion:**

If Dart language used in its primary state as virtual machine then it `compiled to machine code`.

Comment: Sorry, @mezoni, I didn't entirely get that: are you saying that Dart is compiled using JIT? Thanks.

Comment: Dart source can be translated to `tokens` file forcibly. This process called creation of `snapshot` file. Snapshot not a byte code file but just parsed tokens. This snapshot may be executed in VM. Internally VM executes source code or snapshots using JIT technology.

Comment: Although this question is from 7 years ago, but since I started learning Flutter and Dart, thus I have to ask my doubts. Let's say I have 3 classes A, B, C and I have instantiated only A. 
Does this mean that Class B and C are dead codes, which got tokenised but were never used, or 
they never were token either?

Comment: @YashasviBhatt Not a `dead code` but an unused code. Of course, all code tokenized and even precompiled to the intermediate language (not a machine dependent language).

Answer (score -1):

Dart compiles into JavaScript, and JavaScript is an interpreted language. Usually, by 'compiled' languages one understands languages which are compiled into platform-specific machine code, run right on the CPU and don't require an interpreter to run, which is not the case for neither JS nor Dart. So I would say that both JS and Dart are interpreted.

Comment: Thanks Wraychus, but firstly: from what I understood, Dart could be either interpreted/compiled by the Dart VM _or_ translated to JS. So my question is: when using the Dart VM, is it compiled or interpreted? Secondly, if both languages are interpreted, then the sentence I quoted by Lars Bak makes no sense to me. Any other explanation?

Comment: Dart VM executes Dart source code, there is no need to first compile Dart code to byte code (as opposed to Java for instance).

Comment: So it was a long time ago. Currently exists at least four technologies. 1. Interpreted (primitive languages). 2. Compiled to binary files. 3. Translated to byte code + executed in VM + compiled before execution. 4. Distributed as scripts + executed in VM + compiled before execution. Javascript and Dart is number #4.